# Select all records where ID appears once SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct, row-number

I have a table of the form:

```
User1 A
User2 A
User2 B
User3 C
User4 A
User4 C
User5 D
```

and out of this I need to pick **ONLY the users who appear once**. So for example, from the above I want User1, User3, User5. I could use something like `row_number()` to remove duplicates, however this would return one row for all users, even those who have more than 1 entry, which is not what I want. I can't use `DISTINCT` either as for example `User2 A` and `User2 B` would not be caught as they are not equal.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention `row_number()`.  MySQL does not support that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
select username
from t
group by username
having count(*) = 1;
```

If you know there are no duplicates in the second column, then with the right indexes the following might be faster:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.username = t.username and t2.col2 <> t.col2);
```